# AES password storing issue

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I would like to AES encrypt some users profiles info.
When a user registers, I use the password he provides, I compleate it to 16 bits with  zeros to have the required key lenght (16 bit) for AES if the password does not have 16 in lenght, then I encrypt all his data profile with that key. I know that at this point my AES keys will be secure because no one knows them except the users them selves.

When a user logs in, I take his password do the same 16 bit process and decrypt his data. The problem I have is with password recovery, if the user forget his password, the data is lost forever. Is there a better way or a work around this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about cryptography engineering and belongs on crypto.stackexchange.com.

Comment: another point here is that you are probably mixing up bits and bytes ... additionally your key derivation method is not secure since you derive probably from ascii bytes, just by adding zero bits ... that reduces the keyspace ... employ something safer here ... like pbkdf2

Comment: I would ask what value there is in storing the profile info, if no-one but the person whose data it is can ever see it.  Why collect data you don't/can't ever use?  You've made a write-only memory.

Comment: You are missunderstanding me, the whole point is : where to store the AES key. If I follow my logic, I don't need to care about storing it, the only issue is when the user lost his password then all data encrypted is lost. That's what I'm loking for a solution for.

Answer (score 1):

Your AES key "derivation" is **not** secure, you should use password hashing (or, to be more precise, use a password based key derivation function - PBKDF) instead of padding with zero's. A password is **not** the same thing as a key, which should consists of 128 or more randomized bits.

Instead of recovering the key (or password) you could encrypt your data with a random data key. Then you can in turn encrypt this data key with the key of the user. You can *additionally* encrypt the data key using a public (RSA) key, of which you keep the private key safe on detached storage or somewhere in the back office. The encryption of one key with another key is called *key wrapping*.

Some data you may want to keep private to the user, in that case simply do not encrypt with the public key in the back office. You could possibly encrypt this kind of data *at the location of the user* instead of on your server.